# using python virtual env in R

Tags: python, r, virtualenv

I am using 'rPython' package for calling python within R but I am unable to make R refer to my python's virtual environment.

In R, I have tried using

```
system('. /home/username/Documents/myenv/env/bin/activate')
```

but after running the above my python library path does not change (which I check via `python.exec(print sys.path)`). When I run

```
python.exec('import nltk')
```

I am thrown the error:

> Error in python.exec("import nltk") : No module named nltk

although it is there in my virtual env.

I am using R 3.0.2, Python 2.7.4 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Also, I know I can change the python library path from within R by using

```
python.exec("sys.path='\your\path'")
```

but I don't want this to be entered manually over and over again whenever a new python package is installed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Use the "activate" bash script **before running R, so that the R process inherits the changed environment variables**.

```
$ source myvirtualenv/bin/activate

$ R
```

Now rPython should be able to use the packages in your virtualenv.

Works for me. May behave strangely if the Python version you made the virtualenv with is different to the one rPython links into the R process.

Comment: Can you do it for Rstudio?

Comment: R script has to use multiple different virtual envs

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @PaulHarrison's answer, you can mimic what `.../activate` is doing directly in the environment (before starting python from R).

Here's one method for determining what vars are modified:

```
$ set > pyenv-pre
$ . /path/to/venv/activate
(venvname) $ set > pyenv-post
(venvname) $ diff -uw pyenv-pre pyenv-post
```

This gave me something like:

```
--- pyenv-pre 2018-12-02 15:16:43.093203865 -0800
+++ pyenv-post 2018-12-02 15:17:34.084999718 -0800
@@ -33,10 +33,10 @@
 OPTERR=1
 OPTIND=1
 OSTYPE=linux-gnu
-PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+PATH=/path/to/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
 PIPESTATUS=([0]="0")
 PPID=325990
-PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
+PS1='(venvname) \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
 PS2='> '
 PS4='+ '
 PWD=/
@@ -50,10 +50,13 @@
 TERM=xterm
 UID=3000019
 USER='helloworld'
+VIRTUAL_ENV=/path/to/venv
 XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/3000019
 XDG_SESSION_ID=27577
-_=set
+_=/path/to/venv/bin/activate
+_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
 __git_printf_supports_v=yes
 __grub_script_check_program=grub-script-check
 _backup_glob='@(#*#|*@(~|.@(bak|orig|rej|swp|dpkg*|rpm@(orig|new|save))))'
@@ -2390,6 +2393,31 @@
         fi;
     fi
 }
+deactivate () ... rest of this function snipped for brevity
```

So it appears that the important envvars to update are:

- `PATH`: prepend the venv bin directory to the existing paths
- `VIRTUAL_ENV`: set to `/path/to/venv`

I believe the other changes (`OLD_VIRTUAL_*` and `deactivate () ...`) are optional and really only used to back-out the venv activation.

Looking at the `.../activate` script verifies these are most of the steps taken. Another step is unset `PYTHONHOME` if set, which may not be shown in the diff above if you didn't have it set previously.

To R-ize this:

```
Sys.setenv(
  PATH = paste("/path/to/venv/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep = .Platform$path.sep),
  VIRTUAL_ENV = "/path/to/venv"
)
Sys.unsetenv("PYTHONHOME") # works whether previously set or not
```

Comment: I will stick to my extended `bash -c '...'` call but your solution seems to be the best from all others.

Comment: I agree ... it's generally safer to let the system do the envvar management itself. The only disadvantage to the `system` method is that you have to be able to call `python` manually (for the R interaction). One of the python-enablers has `reticulate::use_virtualenv()` (which precludes this necessity), not sure about the others. I prefer yours for simplicity and principle, though I suspect that doing it with `Sys.setenv` is generally safe-enough.

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck getting scripts to use my peynv installation by using:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

So maybe try pointing R to that path (sans `#!`, of course).

Answer (score 0):

manage to get it working by using `bash -c`:

```
system("/bin/bash -c \"source ./pydatatable/py-pydatatable/bin/activate && python -c 'import datatable as dt; print(dt.__version__)'\"")
```